# Is Render UI from backend service a good design?

Tags: php, rest, design-patterns, yii

I read some MVC framework for web application like play-framework, yii etc. They want to let server side to render the UI and send it to the browser side. Please see below yii code as an example,

I created a php class as below:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    // ...existing code...

    public function actionSay($message = 'Hello')
    {
        return $this->render('say', ['message' => $message]);
    }
}
```

Then I create a view php file:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<?= Html::encode($message) ?>
```

When the render method is called in the action of the controller class, it will render the view and return that to the browser.

I see there are a few frameworks which are using that kind of design pattern. I wander whether it is a good idea from a design point of view. It seems that they combine UI and service together. Whenever we change something on UI, we have to do the corresponding update on server code.

I'd like to separate UI and backend service to different layers. For example, the service can listen on a restful address port over http protocol. And the client side will request/post on these restful interfaces. In this way, the server side doesn't know anything about who is UI/client. It can be browser, mobile or any kind of client.

Which design is a better from design point of view? I just want to get more idea on them. Any feedback is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a very subjective question, so it's possible you might get flagged. Still, I'll offer up my view and if it's helpful, great!

You're right that separating UI from service matters, but you can separate UI and service just fine without having to render the UI on the client.

If you're using PHP, you would create a RESTful API as you said, which is responsible for taking URLs like `/content/143` and returning some JSON. You could then create a rendering front-end that receives requests direct from users, hits your API to fetch the content, then converts that into rendered HTML for the user. I use Guzzle for this and it works great, although you should implement caching in the renderer if you anticipate any serious load.

If you want to put UI rendering on the client, that's fine too: again you would make your API in PHP (I'm only saying that because of your PHP tag), but then create the front-end using a toolkit like React where everything is rendered on the client.

There are advantages to both options, so it's really down to skill availability and your precise use case.

No matter what you choose, using some sort of output templating system is basically a must. Twig is great for this if you want a pure PHP approach. If you try React you'll soon run into something neat called JSX, which is XML that gets compiled down to JavaScript – the syntax is strange at first glance, but then you realise how clever it is.

Comment: I don't know which tag I should use so I put php tag since I am reading yii2 document.  I agree that both way can meet requirements and can cover most use cases. I just want to know whether render UI in the backend is a popular design concept. If my UI and backend are using different language, for example, UI is using html/js, backend is using php, Rendering UI from backend will not be a good design, right?

Comment: Rendering HTML from the back end was the only possible way for a very long time. PHP is a hypertext preprocessor – the clue is right there in the name :)  If you choose to render HTML from PHP, that's perfectly fine. Use Twig or similar, but don't worry that you've made a bad choice. I would suggest, though, at the very least you ensure HTML is just one of several possible output formats – you might also want JSON, Apple News, etc.